# Whitelist rejection for PhoneGap when emulating from command line

Tags: ios, cordova, emulation, whitelist

When I emulate my project through Xcode, I get no whitelist rejections. However, when I run through [the command-line scripts as described by PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_command-line_index.md.html#Command-Line%20Usage_ios) (namely build, emulate, and log), I get these:

```
ERROR whitelist rejection: url='http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js'
```

I have populated my `ExternalHosts` with `*`, which is why this isn't happening through Xcode, but I'm not sure why it's not allowing urls through the command line. Any ideas?

Thanks.